# Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.domain.com/emails.html ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404

Tags: php, arrays, curl

What I'm attempting to do is post multiple url's which are exploded by a line break, get and then concatenate the contents of all files.

The problem is, it returns;

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.domain.com/emails.html )
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   /nfs/c09/h02/mre/137842/domains/domain.com/html/index.php on line 6

For all but the last url.

Things that I've noted;

- I've tried using `urlencode()` but that completely destroys the HTTP request.
- There seems to be a space between the last character of the URL and the closing bracket, when I attempt to enter the url with a space into the browser it works fine (but this could be the browser rewriting an invalid URL?)

Here's my code for good measure;

```
$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);
$allTexts = '';
foreach($urls as $url)
{
    $text = file_get_contents($url);
    if (false === $text)
        continue;

    // proceed with your text, e.g. concatinating it:
    $allTexts .= $text;
}
```

Any advice or comments would be greatly appreciated (although I'd rather not use cURL if I don't need to :))!

Comment: Can you navigate to the `http://www.domain.com/emails.html` URL on your browser? It says 404 on the error message - may be it's not there. 
EDIT: Also, you should use `trim()` and possibly do a simple validation as well [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) perhaps?

Comment: It's definitely there, I'm copying and pasting the urls when they're fully loaded in my browser, `http://www.domain.com/emails.html` is just a placeholder to shorten the url length :). I'll attempt to use trim in a minute, as it seems to be the right function for the job from what I've just read. It has to be the url whitespace really, to give a 404 error, I don't know what else it could be. I'll report back :).

Comment: Be careful with what you're doing with this, think that you're allowing a remote user to send an array with urls to your script and you're making your server to read the contents of that urls. I know it's not the point of that question but i saw this and wanted to advise you.

Comment: If i where to sabotage your server I would definately just give it lots of urls to huge pages and repeat that process until it fails.